# Automator: I want an Applescript to remove the first part of a file name, up to "-". Irregular number of characters before the "_"

Tags: applescript, automator, text, macos

Please, I need help to incorporate an Applescript that allows me to remove all characters before the "*" (including first "*". The files have several "_", but I only want to remove the text before the first one. However, the number of characters varies from file to file. It is not always four...

Example, I need to remove LPLLORMF from the name:
LPLLORMF_1023_PM_48_24_25

I would need to change the name to:
1023_PM_48_24_25

Answer (score 0):

> I want an Applescript to remove the first part of a file name, up to “-”. Irregular number of characters before the “_”

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* shows one method to accomplish that:

```
set oriFilename to "LPLLORMF_1023_PM_48_24_25"

set newFilename to ¬
    characters ((offset of "_" in oriFilename) + 1) thru -1 of ¬
    oriFilename as string
```

Which would return:

```
1023_PM_48_24_25
```

Comment: That's perfect, just what I need to include in an Automator workflow. Thank you very much and have a nice weekend.

Comment: @Charly, I appreciate the thanks, however please have a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and if this answers your question and if you would like to mark this as the accepted answer, that would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I need to make a new query. The Script I have received correctly removes the text before the "_" ("_" included). The issue now is that I need the Script to keep the rest of the name intact, regardless of what it is. Currently the Script removes the first part, but the resulting text is always "1023_PM_48_24_24_25". I need a Script that supports different text below. Sometimes it could be, for example "1025_RD_34_18_12". The second question is how to get the Script to batch rename multiple files once the first part of the text is removed. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Charly, RE: "I need to make a new query." --  I was under the impression that this answer  provided you what you where asking  for in your OP and if you need to make a new query, **then please start a new question** and keep in mind, **one question per question please**.

Comment: @Charly Two things… remove the first line from your workflow and have the workflow provide the appropriate filename. Second, please accept the answer. Regards.

Comment: Sorry Mockman, could you tell me how the AppleScript should look like. If I remove 

set oriFilename to "LPLLORMF_1023_PM_48_24_24_25"

I get an error: The variable oriFilename is not set, can you help me.....

Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to do (applescript? automator? one file? a folder of files?) Too many unknowns here. I had the impression that you had a workflow and just needed one last piece of the puzzle. Anyway, you need to set oriFilename based on the filename you wish to process. If it's an applescript, you could do something like `set oriFilename to name of (choose file)`, if it's part of a workflow then one of your actions should provide the filename to set it.

Comment: Charly, @Mockman,  Based on the original question asked and answered I think the comments/question should stop here as the original question has been answered. Any further comments/questions should be focused on Charly's follow up posted question:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/422185/automator-batch-rename-irregular-names