# Batch rename (irregular names) in Automator

Tags: applescript, automator, macos

I need help to incorporate an AppleScript that allows me to remove all characters before the underscore `_`, including the first `_`.

The files have several `_`, but I only want to remove the text before the first one. However, the number of characters varies from file to file. It is not always as shown in the example, the key part is removing up to and including the first underscore, `_`.

The issue is that I need the script to keep the rest of the name intact, regardless of what it is.  I need a script that supports different text below.

Example:

I have this item:
"LPLLORMF_1023_PM_48_24_25"

I need to remove the first part of the name, in this case "LPLLORMF_"

Result: "1023_PM_48_24_25"

The second part, 1023_PM_48_24_25 in this case, wont always be the same, I mean that I would like to maintain this part whatever it may be. It could be "1433_PM_58_25_22" or "1483_FM_51_15_02".

```
set oriFilename to "LPLLORMF_1023_PM_48_24_25"

set newFilename to ¬
    characters ((offset of "_" in oriFilename) + 1) thru -1 of ¬
    oriFilename as string
```

This script correctly removes the first part of the name. However, it does not respect the original name of the second part of the name, it always uses "1023_PM_48_24_25".

The second question is how to get the script to batch rename multiple files once the first part of the text is removed?

I am trying to organize a massive file renaming in Automator.Every day I generate about 300 files, so I need to create a workflow to sort them. Depending on the original name, each one will be given a new specific name. Subsequently, each file will be moved to a different folder. At the moment everything works correctly in Automator.The only thing I have not managed to do, is to remove the first part of the text (which may contain 3, 4 or 5 characters and the subsequent underscore) without altering the rest of the original name.

user3439894, I really appreciate your help. When I run your Script, it does indeed remove the first characters (including the first underscore), but the following text is not retained. It is replaced by "1023_PM_48_24_25". What can I be doing wrong? Thanks again for your help!

Thank you very much for your interest user3439894. I apologize for so many questions, I am an engineer, not a programmer, and this is proving to be more difficult than expected. I currently have a worflow that works (except for removing those first characters), based on identifying files according to some characters in their name, renaming them according to their type, and moving them to different folders.

My idea, to make everything perfect, is to run the AppleScript at the beginning of the workflow, after "Ask for Finder Items". To this path, where the Original items are located, I assign a Variable named "Originals".

So I would have to modify this?
return paragraphs of (do shell script "ls/Volumes/temp/"")??

I have tried to do this without success. How clumsy of me, sorry I DO NOT KNOW HOW TO DO IT.....

Comment: Thank you for adding the additional detail, this makes far more sense! However, please provide the full script you have so far. The code snippet you gave doesn't show how you are setting `oriFilename`, which you mention in the text is actually the issue in your script. Please put the script in a code formatted block (surround by ``` on line above and below the code).

Comment: RE: "This script correctly removes the first part of the name. However, it does not respect the original name of the second part of the name, it always uses "1023_PM_48_24_25"." --  As I'm the one that wrote that _code_, as an answer to another question you asked, I can assure you that it will always return everything past the first underscore regardless of what it is! So, I do not see where you get off saying "it does not respect the original name of the second part of the name". The bottom line is, you are just not incorporating properly into the rest of your **AppleScript** _code_.

Comment: Are these **Finder** _items_, _files_, _folders_ or both?

Comment: You need to include in your question what you already have in your **Automator** _workflow_ and any other _code_ that you are using and how your are using it!  Otherwise, how do you expect we troubleshoot whatever the issue is!?

Comment: You need to understand that the _example_ **AppleScript** _code_ presented in your other question that you are showing here was just that, _example_ **AppleScript** _code_, which means **you** need to adapted it to your needs based on whatever it is your are trying to do. We are not a _code_ writing service and you need to show exactly how you are doing something and where it's not working against what's expected. We are not mind readers!

Comment: Have a look at [this screen shot](https://imgur.com/aG7ZlCD) that shows an example **Automator** _workflow_ using my _example_ **AppleScript** _code_ incorporated into a **Run AppleScript** _action_. You can clearly see it renames the three file name examples in your OP to just that which is after the first underscore.

Comment: Also note that `set newFilename to characters ((offset of "_" in oriFilename) + 1) thru -1 of oriFilename as string` can be written as `set newFilename to text ((offset of "_" in oriFilename) + 1) thru -1 of oriFilename` as there are usually several (or more) ways to do something. Also, this _example_ **Automator** _workflow_ as coded only works with _files_ not _folders_, and why the **System Events** _command_ is wrapped in a `try` _statement_.

Comment: Charly, The linked _example_ **Automator** _workflow_ and in particular the `return paragraphs of (do shell script "ls /Volumes/Temp/")` _command_ was just to show you that files of different names can and did indeed get renamed based on the criteria you mentioned, and showing **a method of** utilizing the _example_ **AppleScript** _code_. It was not meant as an _example_ for production per se, and why I posted it as I did because were/are waiting for the missing information to advise otherwise. To be honest, without seeing the **Automator** _workflow_ I hesitate to tell you how to proceed...

Comment: because it's just easier with all the pieces to provide the better solution.

Comment: You can do something like https://i.imgur.com/jupylzB.jpeg where you use an **Ask for Finder Items** _action_ again after the **Run AppleScript** _action_ to acquire the proper _fully qualified pathnames_ of the renamed _files_.  Note the **[Options]** setting on the second **Ask for Finder Items** _action_.  There is also a way of passing the new _fully qualified pathnames_ of the renamed _files_ from the **Run AppleScript** _action_ to the next _action_, however without seeing your **Automator** _workflow_ I'm not going to write _code_ based on what is still and unknown factor.

Answer (score 0):

> My idea, to make everything perfect, is to run the AppleScript at the beginning of the workflow, after "Ask for Finder Items".

You can use the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* in a **Run AppleScript** *action* in an **Automator** *workflow* directly after an **Ask for Finder Items** *action*, and it will pass a *list* of **Finder** *aliases* of the newly renamed *files* to the next **Automator** *action*:

---

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
on run {input, parameters}
    
    set newFilenameList to {}
    
    repeat with thisItem in input
        
        set oriFilename to the POSIX path of thisItem
        
        set newFilename to ¬
            text ((offset of "_" in oriFilename) + 1) ¬
                thru -1 of oriFilename
        
        try
            tell application "System Events" to ¬
                set name of file oriFilename to newFilename
        end try
        
        set newPathFilename to getDirNameOf(oriFilename) & newFilename
        set newPathFilename to POSIX file newPathFilename
        set newPathFilename to newPathFilename as alias
        copy newPathFilename to the end of newFilenameList
        
    end repeat
    
    return newFilenameList
    
end run

to getDirNameOf(FQP)
    set FQP to the reverse of characters of FQP as string
    set FQP to text (offset of "/" in FQP) thru -1 of FQP
    set FQP to the reverse of characters of FQP as string
    return FQP
end getDirNameOf
```

---

**Notes:**

Replace the default *code* of the **Run AppleScript** *action* with the *example* **AppleScript** *code* shown above.

The **Automator** *action* prior to this, the **Ask for Finder Items** *action*, should be set to: 
 **Type: [Files] [√] Allow Multiple Selection**

As currently coded, the *example* **AppleScript** *code* only renames *files*, not *folders*.

If you want to return a *list* of **POSIX path file names** instead of **Finder** **aliases**, then remove or comment out:

```applescript
set newPathFilename to POSIX file newPathFilename
set newPathFilename to newPathFilename as alias
```

---

The other option is to use a second **Ask for Finder Items** *action* after the **Run AppleScript** *action* as shown in this [*example* **Automator** *workflow*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPG2j.jpg), including its *code*, to acquire the proper *fully qualified pathnames* of the renamed *files*. Note the **[Options]** setting on the second **Ask for Finder Items** *action* in the linked image.

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much for your AppleScript, I run first Ask for Finder Items (Allow multiple ítems), and then the Script, which works correctly only on one of the files.The rest remain unrenamed. I have tried adding a delay, but it does not solve the problem. What can it be?....

Comment: @Charly, RE: "which works correctly only on one of the files.The rest remain unrenamed." --  Did you select more than one _file_ when the **Ask for Finder Items** _action_ opened the window to select the _files_? As you can see in [this screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/wIFgrlC.jpg) it clearly renames all three selected _files_ matching the naming criteria you've given. Also note that I always test _code_ that I post and it does indeed work as stated and the screenshot proves it too! I'm sorry but there is nothing else I can do for you.

Comment: user3439894 6, I do select all files before running AppleScript (allow multiple selection) and I have exactly the same worfkflow as in your example; however, it only renames one file. I'm going on a trip tomorrow and won't be able to try again for another two weeks. I can't tell you how much I need to find a solution. Doing it manually is crazy!.
Thank you very much for your help.